# Exporting image sequence as an animated 3D object?

Tags: animation, export, image-sequence

With [this amazing tutorial](https://youtu.be/0tFe9dashgI) (5:56 - 10:00) I imported my video as PNG image sequence and with the depth maps made it into an animated 3D image sequence. (But this is all just a plane object)

[image]

How to export this 3D animated image sequence as an animated 3D object? I need to have it in Unreal Engine animated, 3-dimensional and extruded like this. I only found explanations on how to export this as a video or IMG sequence (which it already is).

My version is 2.93
And please have in mind when answering that I'm not too good with Blender, so imagine you're talking to a complete beginner lol!

Comment: If I understood properly, in general, you can't just 'export' to convert from a planar 2D image to the underlying 3D information it appears to be a window into. There are methods for taking large numbers of static 2D images, e.g. photos taken from different angles, and automatically trying to build a corresponding 3D model, but this generally requires more than just one angle, and is not as simple as exporting from one file type to another; it usually requires trial-and-error. This area of work is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_from_motion; there are some Blender addons for this.

Comment: In case it helps, the basic reason this isn't just a straightforward export is that any given 2D image contains strictly less (a *lot* less) information than a full 3D model. Going from 2D to 3D requires a fairly complex process for trying to extrapolate from the 2D information to corresponding 3D information. Structure-from-motion algorithms attempt to do this by assuming they have access to many different perspectives on the same fixed 3D object.

Comment: Hi @NeverConvex thank you very much for your answers. Just to clarify - are you talking about photogrammetry? This is how this image sequence looks in motion in Blender  https://youtube.com/shorts/ZS0WhLrkLgM - I would like to have it like that in Unreal Engine as well, regardless if it's a 3D object or an extruded image sequence. I just thought as I achieved it here already there would be an easy way to transfer it like that directly to Unreal. Maybe I should try it there directly from scratch?

Comment: Yes, SfM is a specific photogrammetry technique, as I understand it. And -- oh, I think I misunderstood your goal; you want to convert a preexisting extrusion to a 3D model; I didn't appreciate from your original question that you already have the extrusion present. That may be more easily doable, then; will try to come back later if no one else suggests a method first

Comment: Just as a quick suggestion: have you tried clicking `Apply` on each of the modifiers (starting from the one on the bottom, first)? I usually work with static rather than sequences of images, but I think this should, at least for a single frame, convert your plane into a fairly complex object with the expected 3D structure. I am a little unsure if it will automatically handle that you have a sequence of images correctly; suspicious that may require writing some `Python` code, but won't be certain until I also try

Comment: @NeverConvex thanks for getting back to me! When I export it as .fbx or .gltf it does export it with all the extruded surface and the image texture. But it's just one frozen frame. Would it help if I sent you the blender file? And regarding the Apply button, I can't find it in the Modifier segment? And unfortunately I can't code.

Comment: The `Apply` button should appear on each modifier in your modifier stack, in the top-left of it (e.g., see this Mirror modifier example for reference: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/_images/modeling_modifiers_introduction_mirror-subdiv1.png). It sounds like the export process is already applying the modifiers, though, so your real problem is that export doesn't know you want to generate a 3D model complete with animation. Uploading your `.blend` would help; I'm not sure linking the frames is trivial, but it will be interesting to try

Comment: @NeverConvex amazing, thanks a lot! Here's the link to the file:
https://we.tl/t-SrHnxrL8jY

Comment: @NeverConvex hey, I managed to do it in Unreal Engine!! https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/image-sequence-3d-extruded-with-depth-maps/852901/2 here's the topic with my explanation, this tutorial helped me a lot! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GkS9-94k80

Comment: Oh, nice! I had not had a chance to open the Blend file and try yet. You might consider adding an `Answer` to your question below, explaining how you solved your problem (for other users who may come across it).

Comment: @NeverConvex oh sure, thanks, I'll do that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure how to export this, but my main goal was achieving the same thing in Unreal Engine (and even additionally the background transparency) which I did!

So first I added an image sequence as explained [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/WorkingWithMedia/IntegratingMedia/MediaFramework/HowTo/ImgMediaSource/), for both the base color and another one for the depth maps.
Then I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GkS9-94k80) to "extrude" it (displacement/tessellation).

I achieved background transparency by setting the material type to "masked" and then plugging the media texture's alpha channel into the "opacity mask" option.

I initially achieved the transparency in my image sequence by editing the first image in Photoshop and exporting it as .png, and then using the amazing program [Ebsynth](https://ebsynth.com/) to generate the rest of the sequence like that based on the first one.